# How to use `from` sub query in JPA QUERY DSL?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, backend, querydsl

I have a query sql:

```sql
select distinct a.* from (select * from product_sku) a, (select @rowno:= 0) t;
```

Now, I want to perfrom my sql in query dsl:

```java
jpaQuery.selectDistinct(qProductSku).from(query, jpaQuery.select(Expressions.numberTemplate(Integer.class, "@rowno:=0")));
```

I have already named `a` with `query`. Its type is `JPAQuery<ProductSkuEntity>`. The type of `jpaQuery` is `JPAQueryFactory`.

But it is incorrect, because `from` method only accpt type `EntityPath`.

How could I transfrom it to query dsl correctly?

(Don't ask me why this SQL is so strange, it just a part of complete expression)

Answer (score 0):

```
   SQLQuery sqlQuery = new SQLQuery(connection, PostgresTemplates.builder().quote().newLineToSingleSpace()
            .printSchema().build());

    ListSubQuery<Tuple> listSubQuery = new SQLSubQuery().from(QUsersPasswords.usersPasswords).orderBy(QUsersPasswords.usersPasswords.usuNummat.desc()).list(QUsersPasswords.usersPasswords.all());

    QUsersPasswords qSubquery = new QUsersPasswords("subquery");

    sqlQuery.from(listSubQuery.as("subquery")).limit(10);

    sqlQuery.list(qSubquery.all());
```